# Rodando em Múltiplas telas

Tags: android, android-layout

Como definir um layout para rodar em múltiplas telas sem precisar criar vários Layouts?

É possível ou teria que criar Layouts específicos?

Comment: `Layout` você tem que criar sempre, o que é possível é chamar um `Layout`em uma `Fragment`, pelo que eu sei.

Answer (score 4):

O sistema de resources do Android vai escolher o layout mais adequado para a tela do dispositivo de acordo com os diretórios layout-small, layout-normal, layout-large e layout-xlarge. Além disso, você também pode ter as definições por orientação com os qualificadores land e port. E podendo combinar tamanho e orientação.

Então, cabe a você desenvolvedor criar os layouts de acordo com as telas que precisa. O caminho é testar e ver como o desenho das suas telas ficam em telas maiores e menores, sendo que você não é obrigado a ter todas as combinações para layout.

Por exemplo, se você acha que para as telas small, normal e large o mesmo layout se aplica, e deseja criar apenas um especial para tablets, você precisaria então de uma pasta layout e outra layout-xlarge. Assim, todas que são de large "para baixo" usariam o layout na pasta layout e somente o tamanho específico seria utilizado o layout-xlarge.

Além disso, você precisa se atentar ao tamanho das imagens utilizadas também, pois os diferentes dispositivos possuem diferentes densidades de pixel. Assim, se você fizer apenas uma imagem para todas as densidades, pode ter imagens muito grandes em uma tela e muito pequena em outras.

Mas, isso não significa que você tem que ter layouts para cada tamanho de imagem. Pois os layouts são responsáveis pela organização dos elementos na tela. Para as imagens, você vai utilizar a pasta drawable com os qualificadores de densidade ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi e etc.

Na documentação [oficial do Android](http://developer.android.com) existe um guia dedicado a explicar detalhadamente os qualificadores, boas práticas e tudo mais que você precisa saber para suportar multiplas telas. Dê uma olhada no guia [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Answer (score 1):

Se o que você pretende é usar o mesmo layout em várias telas(layouts) você só tem que criar um xml com o layout que quer reaproveitar e na tela onde quer usá-lo colocar este comando:

```
<include layout="@layout/nome_do_layout" />
```

Melhor ainda, como sugere Felipe Avelar, será utilizar `Fragments`.
Além de reaproveitar o `layout`, você reaproveita o código associado a ele.

Se você se refere a utilizar o layout em diferentes ***devices***, com diferentes densidades e dimensões, a resposta é sim.
Claro que isto só se aplica se você achar que o layout não fica bem no ***device*** em questão.

Sempre que você utilizar imagens ou icons, deverá ter um por cada densidade

Comment: Ramaral, me refiro a utlizar o layout em diferentes devices. Essa é uma dificuldade ainda que encontro no desenvolvimento da plataforma Android, ter que prever um layout para inúmeros aparelhos. Obrigado pela ajuda